как удалить header при загрузке сайта
Как можно удалить два хедера при загрузке сайта (Iframe option и ContentSecurityPolicy (может ошибся, но смысл тот же). Можно удалять через расширение хрома, но т.к я пишу через селениум на питоне это будет тяжеловато, можно ли как то при загрузке отключать эти хедеры, как делает это расширение?
